# Is there a specification for the model.config file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there a specification for the model.config file available online?

Specifically, is there a  tag and are multiple  tags permissible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1502/is-there-a-specification-for-the-model.config-file?/) by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 86 on 2013-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-02-23**:
Well, gazebo didn't throw any errors or warnings at me when I included those tags, but I still don't know if there is an official specification for the file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Documentation for the model database is in the User Guide: http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html

We need to update the document to use "model.config" instead of "manifest.xml"

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-07**:
Is the filename the only thing that changed? I assumed that was out of date since it seemed to only make reference to manifest.xml.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-03-07**:
Only the filename changed.

**Comment by [dereck](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/219/dereck/) on 2013-03-07**:
Cool, thanks. :)